# setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER) - CENTER cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, border-layout

in two different classes (both extending JFrame) of my project, I try to do this:

```
    header = new JLabel("Header");
    header.setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
    add(header, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

one works, the other dosent. Error message: "CENTER cannot be resolved to a variable". I use Eclipse, and when I try to invoke this method, it doesen't propose any of the other constants like LEFT, RIGHT(... so I suppose those are unknown to. I dont get how a constant can not be resolved in one class and is unknow to the other. I tryied coping all the imports from the class where the line works to the one where it dosn't, without effect. Apart from the alignment the label workes fine.

Comment: header.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER). I actually think it comes from SwingConstants, but JLabel implements it

Comment: That worked, thanks. Could you explain, why it workes without that, in the other clas?

Comment: The other class probably implements SwingConstants or something that implements it....

Comment: An of topic question: as you didn't answer, but comment, how can I set this question to answered?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Why don't you add this as an answer?

Comment: @tobias_k Because I'm sitting on the couch with my iPad and it's to much effort to type it in as answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a class (or interface) which contains the constant you are using, something like

```
header.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
```

for example.

`CENTER` comes from `SwingConstants` which is implemented by such classes as `JLabel` and many of the Swing classes, this is likely why you didn't need to reference it directly.

Comment: Or you could make a static import with that particular constant.

Comment: @Ordous I'm not very keen on static imports for the very reason we have this question, but thats just me